# SVN: svn:ignore is not ignoring contents of directory

Tags: svn, svnignore

This is driving me up the wall.

I have a laravel project and I'm using subversion for version control. Laravel projects have a folders:

```
app/storage/cache
app/storage/logs
app/storage/meta
app/storage/sessions
app/storage/views
```

I need each of the subfolders, but I don't want their contents in my repository. I also *super super* do not want the contents to show up in my list when I run `svn status`.

I tried adding the `svn:ignore` property to each folder by using:

```
svn propset svn:ignore * .
```

But EVERYTHING in the subfolders still show as files ready to be added when I run `svn status`

I've seen people use `svn propset svn:ignore *.* .` to ignore everything in a folder. I gave that a try as well but it still doesn't work (likely because the files normally do not have an extension which makes the pattern not match).

Is there something I'm misunderstanding??

EDIT:

Here's the output for the commands `svn proplist` and `svn status`:

```
[chriss-mbp:storage]: svn proplist *
Properties on 'cache':
  svn:ignore
Properties on 'logs':
  svn:ignore
Properties on 'meta':
  svn:ignore
Properties on 'sessions':
  svn:ignore
Properties on 'views':
  svn:ignore

[chriss-mbp:storage]: svn status
?       logs/laravel.log
?       meta/services.json
?       sessions/3a792417f991b8eb744c06ce73a616604fcca6d3
?       views/7a8aece605b3d3e46f3aa693f077c301
?       views/93279b38fe9be84844babfd1c383f74d
?       views/bbf7bfd90b52526ecd113046a994d2b0
?       views/f2824491ec74e36ce353ab66ce66ad11
```

UPDATE:

So I was able to add in the `svn:ignore` property with the `*` character by going into svnx, selecting the folder that I wanted to add the ignore property to, clicking the property button, and adding `svn:ignore` as a new property and `*` unquoted and unescaped as it's value. This change definitely ignores everything in the folder when viewed via svnx and via command line.

When I go back to the command line and run `svn pl views`, it returns:

```
[chriss-mbp:storage]: svn pl views/
Properties on 'views':
  svn:ignore
```

It's like the ignore property is there but there's no specifics on what to ignore (I guess that means "Ignore everything"?). It's odd, though, that I would be able to add the asterisk in svnx and it doesn't show via command line.

I'm glad that I got the ignore to work, but I don't really understand the exact reasoning behind why it's working. If anyone wants to fill in the blank I'd be happy to give them the check.

Comment: Please, show your `svn pl -v` output with `svn st`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to escape or quote the * you are passing to your command, to prevent your shell from expanding it rather than using it as a literal value passed to the `svn propset` command. Or, try using `propedit` or the `-F` flag on propset to load a text editor or pass in a file, respectively.

Comment: I've tried both escaping the asterisk and using a file in the property and neither seems to be doing the trick :/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part of your question (after the UPDATE):

`svn pl views` shows a list of properties set on folder `views`. So you actually just see that a `svn:ignore` property is set but you don't see its contents.

To see contents of properties, you can:

- Use `svn pl -v views` to get a verbose output of the proplist command. This will list all properties and their values.
- Use `svn pg svn:ignore views` to get the contents of property `svn:ignore` (`pg` is an alias for `propget`)